# Move cursor to the begin of TextFormField when lose focus

Tags: dart, flutter, cursor

Imagine the following scenario:

1. Application has a `TextFormField` where the user inputs a big string.
2. The form field will scroll automatically to its right as the user types in, which is expected. So far so good.
3. The `TextFormField` also has a `FocusNode` that will be dismissed when the user completes edition, thus, calling the `onFieldSubmitted()`, and requesting the new focus to other field, something like:

```
onFieldSubmitted: (_) => FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_someOtherNode);
```

4. Now, I want the loosing focus `TextFormField` to scroll back to its begin instead of leaving the cursor at the end, makes sense right? It turns out that it is actually possible by changing the `value` of its `TextEditingController`

```
_firsFieldController.value = TextEditingValue(
            text: _firstFieldController.text,
            selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: 0),
            composing: TextRange.collapsed(0)));
```

5. This all makes sense and work, until a point. Here's when the problem starts. Changing the `TextEditingController` value will trigger a `ValueNotifier` to all its listeners, but since this is a synchronous process, if I immediately request focus to a new node, the cursor won't be updated to its begin because it's actually required to have the focus on the `TextFormField` that is animating back.

**TL;DR**

This won't work because the focus to the new node will be set before setting the cursor on the begin of the first

```
onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
     _firstFieldController.value = TextEditingValue(
                                  text: _firstFieldController.text,
                                  selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: 0),
                                  composing: TextRange.collapsed(0));
   FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_passwordFocusNode);
}
```

Adding a little delay before requesting the new focus to let the listeners rebuild will make it work, but feels completely wrong

```
Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 200))
                                  .then((_) => FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_newFocusNode));
```

Comment: If anyone gets to answer this, also an additional question, is using a TextEditingController the only solution? I dont want to use one. But I also wish the text cursor to be moved to start when it loses focus.

Comment: i consider this a bug. we should not be forced to use a TextEditingController to make this work. I dont have any use for this and only want to use the initialValue property. I submitted an issue to the flutter repository so they can add this feature.

like in the web, text fields have this default behavior already.